# Age range validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I added age range for my search panel in which the input of AGE_FROM shouldn't be greater than the AGE_TO. AGE_TO should also not be equal to 0, because if I input only on AGE_FROM, the exact age should show(just to be clear)

here's my javascript file. It's not working and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make it work or how to trigger it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    });

    $('#btnAdvanceSearch').click(function () {
        var age_from = document.getElementById('txtAGE').value;
        var age_to = document.getElementById('txtTO').value;

        if (age_from > age_to && age_to !== "") {
            alert('Invalid Age range!');
        }

    }
      )
</script>
```

I'd appreciate any kind of help. Thank you in advance.
the id for my search button is btnAdvanceSearch

Comment: Are you sure that `age_from` and `age_to` have valid values? If you put a breakpoint on the `if` what does the debugger say the values are?

Comment: You are mentioning that it doesn't trigger your code. Try putting your code inside of `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`

Comment: Webforms does have a Range Validator Control that does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Convert input values to `int` by adding `+` in front of them. Also you can set input `type="number"` to allow only numbers.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#btnAdvanceSearch').click(function () {
     var age_from = +$('#txtAGE').val();
     var age_to = +$('#txtTO').val();
          
     if (age_from > age_to && age)
        alert('Invalid Age range!');                 
  })    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='number' id='txtAGE' placeholder='FROM'/>
<input type='number' id='txtTO' placeholder='TO'/>
<input type='button' id='btnAdvanceSearch' value='Search'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse the input to integer. d**ocument.getElementById('txtAGE').value returning a string,** so you need to convert it into integer.

```js
$('#btnAdvanceSearch').click(function () {
    var age_from = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtAGE').value);
    var age_to = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtTO').value);

    if (age_from > age_to && age_to !== "") {
        alert('Invalid Age range!');
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='txtAGE'>
<input type='text' id='txtTO'>
<button type='button' id='btnAdvanceSearch'>click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

```js
function getAgeRange(from, to) {
  function constructRange(from, to) {
    if (!from || from < 1) {
      return null
    }
  
    if (to === '' || from === to) {
      return [from, from]
    }
  
    if (from > to) {
      return null
    }
  
    return [from, to]
  }
  
  var range = constructRange(from, to)
  
  if (range) {
    return range.map(function(x) {
      return parseInt(x)
    })
  }
  
  return range
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#btnAdvanceSearch').click(function() {
    var from = jQuery('#txtAGE').val()
    var to = jQuery('#txtTO').val()
   
    var range = getAgeRange(from, to)
    
    if (!range) {
      alert('Invalid Age range!')
      return false
    }
    
    if (range[0] == range[1]) {
      alert('Search exact age: ' + range[0])
      return true
    }
    
    alert('Search in age range: ' + range[0] + ' - ' + range[1])
    return true
  })
})

// quick tests
assert('Empty fields gives null', getAgeRange('', ''), null)
assert('Age can\'t be 0', getAgeRange('0', ''), null)
assert('Age can\'t be negative', getAgeRange('-1', ''), null)
assert('If only age given, return [age, age]', getAgeRange('1', ''), [1, 1])
assert('If age equals to, return [age, age]', getAgeRange('1', '1'), [1, 1])
assert('If to is greater than age, return [age, to]', getAgeRange('1', '2'), [1, 2])
assert('If age is greater than to, return null', getAgeRange('2', '1'), null)


function assert(message, x, y) {
  function equals(x, y) {
    if (y== null) {
      return x === y
    }
  
    return x.reduce(function(acc, value, key) {
      return value == y[key]
    }, false)
  }
  
  if (!equals(x, y)) {
    console.error('Failed: ' + message + '. Expected: ' + x + ' but got ' + y)
  }
  else {
    console.info('Success: ' + message)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="txtAGE" />
  <input type="number" id="txtTO" />
  <button id="btnAdvanceSearch">Search</button>
```